# Prevent New Dialog While Another one is open in Quasar Framework

Tags: dialog, quasar

I have a little problem with my seamless dialog in quasar framework. I use vue 3. I open a from discussion seamless form dialog box with following code:

```
function newDiscussion () {
    q.dialog({
        component: DiscussionForm,
        componentProps: {
            formTitle: 'Create Discussion',
        }
    }).onOk(() => {
        // 
    }).onCancel(() => {
    // console.log('Cancel')
    }).onDismiss(() => {
    // console.log('I am triggered on both OK and Cancel')
    })
}
```

since my custom dialog component is seamless I can interact with rest of the page and when I click create new discussion button again, it opens new dialog onto existing one.. How can I detect dialog is already open and control it?